# When using rewrite engine I get 404

Tags: apache2

I tried setting up rewrites in my `.htaccess`.

It looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^main/?$ main.php [NC,L]
```

When I try to go to `/main/` I get status 404, but if I create a folder `main`, it starts working perfectly. What could be the problem?

My apache error logs shows this:

```
[Sun Jul 15 21:57:44.934337 2018] [negotiation:error] [pid 5527] [client ::1:49702] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /home/mykolas/public_html/main (None could be negotiated).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of googling I finally found the solution. I just needed to disable MultiViews in my root directory in vhosts file.